# Generating random integer in python fails using random library

Tags: python, random

Below is the snippet:

```
C:\APPS>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> random.seed()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'seed'
>>> random.randint(0,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randint'
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have any other modules with name `random`?

Comment: I tried it, but didn't have any errors.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a file called `random.py` in the `APPS` directory. Delete or rename that file.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this to see which random module you're using:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: print(random.__file__)
/usr/lib/python3.2/random.py
```